# how to make file accessible to administrators only?

Tags: c#, .net, security, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setting UAC settings of a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737196/setting-uac-settings-of-a-file-in-c-sharp)

I want to set file permissions so only those with administrative privileges can change it.

Can anyone give me a good example on how to do this in c#?

**UPDATE**

I've tried various things with `FileSecurity`, and I simply can't get a hang of it.

Here are the permissions that I'd like to impose on file:

[image]

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Comment: excuse me? what's wrong with the post? I don't see a good answer here on how to set administrator access permissions on a file using FileSecurity. This is not a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Administrators can access anything (doesn't matter privileges, so the problem will be other users. The fourth argument of `System.Io.File.Create`. is an `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity` object. That's what you need.