# How get programmatically in C# Compatibility properties about application Executable?

Tags: c#, properties, compatibility, executable, administrator

I have a Windows Form application, or Console Application like ImpersonatorTester.Executor.exe.

Now, this steps:

1. Right-click about ImpersonatorTester.Executor.exe file.
2. Select Properties.
3. Select Compatibility Tab.

Option *Run this program as an administrator*

Option *Change settings for all users*

*Compatibility for all users Tab.*

Option *Run this program as an administrator*

Now,

How can I get programmatically if an application EXE has "Run this program as an administrator" value ?

and "Run this program as an administrator" value for All Users ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set “Run this program as an administrator” programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313045/how-to-set-run-this-program-as-an-administrator-programatically)