# Windows 10: Compatibility feature bug?

Tags: windows, compatibility

My installer sets a compatibility mode for an app via registry (for all users):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Program\\Program.exe"="RUNASADMIN"
```

Windows 10 ignores this, though, - no UAC prompt until I open properties/compatibility tab, manually deselect "run as admin", and select it back. Another solution is to create an registry entry for the current user as well:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Program\\Program.exe"="RUNASADMIN"
```

Why is this? I've had no problems with creating only HKLM registry keys under Win 7 - the system has always recognized the needed compatibility options.

Comment: Are those registry keys officially documented to do what you need?

Comment: No, but they're being widely used (by GOG in their installers, for example). Also, the keys were discussed on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313045/how-to-set-run-this-program-as-an-administrator-programatically

Comment: Why do you expect Microsoft to not break a contract they never signed? Any reason you aren't going the documented route, and use an application manifest instead (e.g. by using the [/MANIFESTUAC (Embeds UAC information in manifest)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx) linker option)?

Comment: I didn't expect anything. I'm just curious, if the change is intended or is a bug. And yes, the solution you described most likely is the best.

Comment: The change is intended (likely), and certainly not a bug. It changes an implementation detail, not a published contract. With few exceptions, the registry is not an official programming interface.

Comment: If you need to set compatibility flags for an application you can use the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit to create an .sdb file which can be installed via the `sdbinst` command.  (But in this particular case, and assuming you are able to rebuild the executable in question, you should use a manifest as IInspectable suggests.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that do what you are doing you need to add ~ and a space.
As in "~ RUNASADMIN".
This worked for me.
There is more discussion on this at [Windows Ten Forums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/15523-change-compatibility-mode-settings-apps-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Using "~ RUNASADMIN" don't solve the issue described in the question on my computer at least.