# How to make an executable running as administrator with install forge

Tags: registry, setup-project, access-rights

I am using install forge (http://installforge.net/) to produce a setup file for my software. However, the soft recquires admin rights to run for some reasons. One easy solution is to ask the user to "right click -> execute as admin" or any of the similar mehtods. But I want to make it automatically without any user interraction on a Windows 8.1 system.

I found some solutions using the registry in [How to set "Run this program as an administrator" programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313045/how-to-set-run-this-program-as-an-administrator-programatically) but I was unsuccessful when trying it in install forge GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution :

In the InstallForge/System/registry pannel, you have to add a new variable with the following parameters :

[image]

e.g :

- Root key = `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`
- Sub key : `\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` : This is where you want to add the value, keep this exact path, it is standard.
- Value : `<installpath>\pathToYourExe\program.exe` This is the path where your will have your exe installed.
- Value data : `~ RUNASADMIN` (this is specific to windows 8.1 as far as I understood, this value was simply "RUNASADMIN" before that version. (No typo, there is a *space* between "~" and "RUNASADMIN"

You can check that the value has been added by looking at the registry using the regedit.exe command.

Ideally I wanted to add another variable for Root key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE but for some reason the value is not taken into account in the registry when using the same method. However, having only the HKEY_CURRENT_USER is enough for me at the moment.