# How to configure compatibility mode from a script?

Tags: permissions, registry, compatibility

As a part of deployment script I need to add flag "run as admin" for some app. I found where it is configured in registry, but I see that is not enough. For example, I have `procexp64.exe` in `C:\`; I'm adding string value `C:\procexp64.exe` with data `~ RUNASADMIN` in registry in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`. After this I see the checkbox "Run as admin" in exe properties, but actually the app isn't running as admin!

[image]

Ok, I removed my registry modification and configured it manually as show on the pic. The registry value appears back with the same data at the same place. I traced with `procmon` the modification and found that `dllhost` does it - it adds only one registry modification and doesn't modify anything on file system. `dllhosts`'s modification works, but my modification - not. What I'm doing wrong?
Seems like it is not enough to add reg value...
Registry virtualization was disabled, user has admin rights. Win Srv 2012 R2.

Comment: Note that there are two registries, one for 32 bit and one for 64 bit. It could be possible that adding it to the incorrect registry produces this result.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate of: [How to set "Run this program as an administrator" programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313045/how-to-set-run-this-program-as-an-administrator-programmatically)

Make sure you choose HKLM or HKCU correcly

You can try

`reg.exe Add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\procexp64.exe" /d "RUNASADMIN" /f`

or

`reg.exe Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\procexp64.exe" /d "RUNASADMIN" /f`